# Word that means "adding money to a phone payment account"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word that means "adding money into a phone payment account".

I thought of these:

- "recharge"

  Disadvantage: Indian English. Only used in South Asian and Southeast Asian varieties of English.
- "top-up"

  Disadvantage: British English. Only understood by the British. Americans will find this weird.

Is there a better word that means "adding money to a phone payment account"? If there is none, what is an unambiguous phrase that can be used worldwide?

Comment: Top up is American English, too.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I am under the impression that it is not commonly used in American English.

Comment: Related: [To top up something](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/479880).

Comment: I have lived in the US for all my 21 years.