# What do you call the act of increasing the balance on a gift card?

Tags: verbs, terminology

When the credit on a gift card is decreased, we usually call it "redeeming" the gift-card. Even if that leaves the gift card with a positive balance after the transaction.
But what do we call increasing the credit on said gift card? Is it "upgrading the balance"? Or "topping up the gift card"? Or some other turn of phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Top up** seems the usual verb, at least in the UK. I can find this on various websites:

[Marks and Spencer](https://www.marksandspencer.com/c/help/gift-cards-and-egift-cards): "I've spent the money on my gift card. What can I do with it now? ... You can top it up in store."

[Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Amazon-EU-S-%C3%A0-r-l-1_UK_Top_Up-Amazon-co-uk/dp/B08G9L873R): "When you top up, you purchase an Amazon.co.uk Gift Card in an amount of your choice (between £1 and £1000) that will be automatically added to your Amazon.co.uk Gift Card balance."

Also, a tax advice website, [Alexander Myerson & Co](https://www.amyerson.com/trivial-benefits/): "employers would need to be careful if topping up gift card balances throughout the year (e.g., say an employer gave employees a gift card at the start of the tax year with a balance of £20, and proceeded to top-up each card by £20 per month..."

Comment: Not refill like a gas tank or recharge like a cell phone? Maybe replenish like an emergency fund?

Comment: Related: [To top up something](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/479880).